# Parse shell script in Jenkinsfile for testing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When running a jenkins pipeline, I often make error in the shell script (`sh`) and I only detect that error when I run the pipeline. Is there a way to parse the script (using groovy compiler maybe?) and see the actual shell script that would be run by Jenkins beforehand?

An example would be the shell script in the pipeline script below:

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('test') {
         sh """
            echo \${PWD}
         """
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you want to catch ?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to see the actual script that would be executed after all the variable substitution. For instance, what if I did not escape the $ sign in the code above?

Comment: Currently I just do trail and error. I write the script and I run it in a pipeline and try to debug.

Comment: Try to isolate your script and test it locally. Set environment variables and mock commands if needed. You'll go faster that way

Comment: Is there a way to test it without running it in a pipeline? I'm new to Jenkins and not very familiar with groovy.

Comment: I meant isolate your script from Jenkins. You can just run the script from the command line